# Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server, math, overflow

I have a stored procedure which works fine in my local environment as well as the QA environment.

However at the UAT environment at the client it gives the error

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:*
>    *Message number="8115" severity="16" state="8">Arithmetic overflow error
>    converting nvarchar to data type numeric.*

It also works fine in one of the local instances installed in the client location. 
I found out the line of code which gives an error by commenting/umcommenting lines of code and zeroed it down to

```
(
        @TotalHHInternalTo IS NULL
        OR
        (
            IsNumeric(E.[Xml].value(
                                    'declare default element namespace "http://www.xyz/1.0";
                                    (/Event/Data/CustomData/DataXML/ProductData/ProductParty/ProductCategory[@code != ''Protection'']/Product/FundValue)[1]',
                                    'nvarchar(50)'
                                    ) ) = 1
            AND
            EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    1
                FROM E.[Xml].nodes(
                    'declare default element namespace "http://www.xyz/1.0";
                    /Event/Data/CustomData/DataXML/ProductData/ProductParty/ProductCategory[@code != ''Protection'']/Product') as P(E)
                HAVING SUM(P.E.value(
                                        'declare default element namespace "http://www.xyz/1.0";
                                        (FundValue)[1]',
                                        'decimal'
                                        )) <= @TotalHHInternalTo
            )   
        )
     )
```

The variable `@TotalHHInternalTo` is a parameter of type decimal which is part of search criteria passed to the stored procedure as an xml. Under Product party I have 4 product category and I need to total up all Fund value except of type Protection. If the sum of these 3 types is less than  `@TotalHHInternalTo` I would like to display it in the search result.

I added the `isNumeric` condition to check if the value picked up from the xml is a numeric value.

However I still get an overflow error.

Answer (score 1):

Check my brackets, but you need to convert it to explicit short-circuit boolean evaluation using CASE.  SQL Server is free to evaluate `AND` conditions in either order, and you got the wrong end of the stick.

```
        CASE WHEN IsNumeric(E.[Xml].value(
                                'declare default element namespace "http://www.focus-solutions.co.uk/focus360/1.0";
                                (/Event/Data/CustomData/DataXML/ProductData/ProductParty/ProductCategory[@code != ''Protection'']/Product/FundValue)[1]',
                                'nvarchar(50)'
                                ) ) = 0
        THEN 0
        WHEN
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                1
            FROM E.[Xml].nodes(
                'declare default element namespace "http://www.focus-solutions.co.uk/focus360/1.0";
                /Event/Data/CustomData/DataXML/ProductData/ProductParty/ProductCategory[@code != ''Protection'']/Product') as P(E)
            HAVING SUM(P.E.value(
                                    'declare default element namespace "http://www.focus-solutions.co.uk/focus360/1.0";
                                    (FundValue)[1]',
                                    'decimal'
                                    )) <= @TotalHHInternalTo
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: I made the changes as suggested by Richard, it still gives the same error. <Message number="8115" severity="16" state="8">Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.</Message>

Comment: Can you post a fragment of your XML, at least a small part that would cause this error? It shouldn't be too hard to divide and conquer.

Comment: This is the xml from where i am picking up the FundValue:

Comment: <ProductParty id="8b33346f-499d-4fc8-8d2c-ad142b1addfd">
            <ProductCategory code="Protection" />
            <ProductCategory code="Investment">
              <Product>
                <ProductHoldingNumber>12</ProductHoldingNumber>
                <FundValue>80000</FundValue>
                <IndividualQuoteFundValue />
                <AggregatedFundValueOpal />
                <AggregatedFundValueOpalOb />
                <CreatedDate>2012-10-25T11:04:34</CreatedDate>
              </Product>
            </ProductCategory>
           </ProductParty>

Comment: That's not it. Using your original condition doesn't break it here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5625/0)

Comment: It breaks only in the UAT environment, it works fine on my local machine, on my QA box & the clients local machine.

Comment: I just got results of a query that i ran on UAT for picking up the value of External Fund value in the xml and found that one of the value was "6.57467865465465E+33". When i convert this value to double i get the overflow error.

Comment: Yes its a data error, need to provide a validation on screen to limit the value entered. Its Fund value so can never be that large. The issue could have been resolved if i had the data earlier but due to the data being sensitive it took time. Thanks for your help.